# What is the best way, to draw a part of an arraybuffer to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, asm.js

I have an `ArrayBuffer`, and I have a function called module.repaint, which works with the ArrayBuffer. In every redraw call, I would like to put the colors from the ArrayBuffer to the canvas.

I do it like this:

```
imgData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(MEM, 0, siz));
```

But is it possible, to copy a part of the ArrayBuffer to an other faster?
Code:

```
var MEM = new ArrayBuffer(2*1024*1024);
var canvas, ctx, imgData, siz;

var repaint = function() {
    // module.repaint works on the arraybuffer
    module.repaint();

    imgData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(MEM, 0, siz));
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(repaint);
};

var init = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    siz = canvas.width*canvas.height*4;

    imgData=ctx.createImageData(canvas.width,canvas.height);

    repaint();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I didn't check if the gain is important, but I can see some useful optimizations here.

First, `Uint8ClampedArray` is a view to the buffer, not a buffer itself, so you don't need to create it everytime. (You can also have multiple views on a single buffer)

You should also avoid using the `set` method of `imgData.data` because it copies all the data from one array to another (which is useless). Instead, you can set your `Uint8ClampedArray` on the constructor.

With that code, each change on `MEM` will automatically affect `imgData` because `imgData.data` directly points to `MEM`.

```
var MEM = new ArrayBuffer(2*1024*1024);
var canvas, ctx, imgData, siz;

var repaint = function() {
    // module.repaint works on the arraybuffer
    module.repaint();

    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(repaint);
};

var init = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    siz = canvas.width*canvas.height*4;

    imgData = ctx.createImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(MEM, 0, siz), canvas.width, canvas.height);

    repaint();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**If possible, refactor your module.repaint() to use an offscreen canvas instead of a pixel array.**

That way you can just drawImage the offscreen canvas to the onscreen canvas--efficient because the GPU can do the blitting instead of burdening the CPU.

`putImageData` is slower because it involves the CPU fetching data from the pixel array, setting that data in your temp array and transferring the temp array to the onscreen imageData.  These are all activities that burden the CPU and reduce performance.

Comment: The module is an asmjs module. The heap object's byteLength must be a multiple of 4096, and the heap object's byteLength must be a power of 2.

Comment: markE : you're right, the gain in speed of drawImage vs putImageData is tremendous, most probably way above what using asmjs can provide. @IterAtor : what about reading markE's answer ?

Comment: But if I would like to use `drawImage` method, then I have to convert the actual ImageData to an image in every loop.

I have no idea, how to read bytes from an ArrayBuffer, and write pixels to a canvas very fast.